# how to use BackGroundWorker while read and save on DB from Excel file

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a function to load an Excel, read it and then save the information in my DB, while reading and saving the information my interface is blocked. I want to show my user through a progress bar. I know that I must use BackGroundWorker but I don't understand how to implement it in my function

this is my function:

```
private void Btn_Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            DataSet validarnumorder;
            dayNum = dayNumber;

            saveFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            saveFile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            saveFile.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls or .xlsx)|.xls;*.xlsx";
            saveFile.Title = "Open an image";
            saveFile.AddExtension = true;
            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
            load.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            fileName = saveFile.FileName;
                Console.WriteLine(saveFile.SafeFileName);
                Console.WriteLine(saveFile.FileName);
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = false;
                Doc = oXL.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                ooSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)Doc.ActiveSheet;

            if (saveFile.FileName.Equals(""))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No se encontro archivo");
                }
                else
                {
                    //La busqueda de valores en el archivo de excel que se encuentre abierto empieza en la fila 2, por eso a la variable s se le está asignando el valor de 2.
                    s = 2;

                            do
                            {


                    //La variable validarorderNum valida si el número de orden existe en la base de datos, por lo que en caso de que ya exista el número de orden, se lance un mensaje que le indique a la persona que el número de orden ya existe en la aplicación por lo que no puede volverlo a ingresar ya que los número de orden no pueden estar repetidos en el programa.

                    validarnumorder = conexion.fillTable("select NumOrder from [tblAssemblyOrder] where NumOrder='" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "' ");
                    if (validarnumorder.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count == 0)
                           {
                        //Se inicializa un insert en la base de datos en dado caso de que el número de orden no exista en la base de datos y le asigna los valores cargados en el excel con el plan de producción.
                    conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable] ([first] ,[first] ,[first] ,[first],[Users] ,[first], [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + s + "").Value + "','" + dayNum + "', 0, 0, 0, '" + dayNum + "') ");

                   conexion.conexionSql("insert into [mytable2] ([first] ,[first],[first],[first],[first] ,[first],[first], [first],  [first], [first]) values ('" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + 0 + "', '" + null + "','" + "NORMAL" + "', '" + null + "', '" + "Nothing" + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" + s + "").Value + "', '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" + s + "").Value + "') ");


                                }
                                else
                                {
          MessageBox.Show("En el plan cargado se encuentra un número de orden ya existente, el número de orden es: '" + oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value + "'");
                                }
                                s++;
       } while (oXL.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + s + "").Value != null);
                load.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        MessageBox.Show("Información guardada con exito");
         saveFile.FileName = null;
                }
                Doc.Close();
                ooSheet = null;
                Doc = null;
                oXL = null;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se encontro el archivo", "E-Flex");
            }



            ListView();       

    }
```

Comment: You can use `async` Task with progress reporting

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread in order solve your problem

```
 var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
               //your saving file code
            });
        thread.Start();
        thread.IsBackground = true;
```

Comment: this does not support report progress.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn how to use async and await, i think bkgr will be outdated...

```
private BackgroundWorker bgWk_Test;
```

initiate an instance of your bkgr

```
        bgWk_Test = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWk_Test.DoWork += bgWk_Test_Exec_DoWork;
        bgWk_Test.ProgressChanged += bgWk_Test_Exec_ProgressChanged;
        bgWk_Test.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWk_Test_Exec_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bgWk_Test.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bgWk_Test.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

do your long process here,and also send report progress

```
private void bgWk_Test_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
// do your long process here 
....
// report progress
  bgWk_Test.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

progress to the UI

```
private void bgWk_Test_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        your progress bar value ++;
    }
```

this event fire when the bkgr have finished the task

```
private void bgWk_Test_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
// do stuff when you bk is finished...
}
```